# Adding attributes to python objects

Tags: python, object, attributes

It's a thing that bugged me for a while. Why can't I do:

```
>>> a = ""
>>> a.foo = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

...while I can do the following?

```
>>> class Bar():
...     pass
... 
>>> a = Bar()
>>> a.foo = 10 #ok!
```

What's the rule here? Could you please point me to some description?

Comment: btw, you should be using `class Bar(object):` instead of `class Bar():` so you get a new-style class

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can add attributes to any object that has a `__dict__`.

- `x = object()` doesn't have it, for example.
- Strings and other simple builtin objects also don't have it.
- Classes using `__slots__` also do not have it.
- Classes defined with `class` have it unless the previous statement applies.

If an object is using `__slots__` / doesn't have a `__dict__`, it's usually to save space. For example, in a `str` it would be overkill to have a dict - imagine the amount of bloat for a very short string.

If you want to test if a given object has a `__dict__`, you can use `hasattr(obj, '__dict__')`.

[This](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#the-dynamic-dict) might also be interesting to read:

> Some objects, such as built-in types and their instances (lists, tuples, etc.) do not have a `__dict__`. Consequently user-defined attributes cannot be set on them.

Another interesting article about Python's data model including `__dict__`, `__slots__`, etc. is [this](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) from the python reference.