# Adding methods to pyodbc

Tags: python, design-patterns, pyodbc

Is it possible to add methods to the pyodbc Row class (with subclassing or Decorator pattern I guess, but I don't know how to implement them)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not, because none of the pyodbc objects have a __dict__ attribute, thus preventing any user attributes from being added/patched. Explanation here - [Adding attributes to python objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907937/adding-attributes-to-python-objects)

However, if your memory/performance requirements allow, you can get around this by using **pypyodbc** which is the pure python implementation of pyodbc. I just tested this because I wanted to subclass Connection, which works as well as dynamically adding new attributes to Row objects.

Here's another possible route to explore using ctypes - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24498525/1045885